# Android eclipse SignUp page app has stopped error

Tags: php, android, mysql, eclipse

This android project use a database in server from php mysql. In the Activity that should register data to database on server. But it  can't be registered and the app has stoped. It go back login activity from signup activity. Here is the picture of Logcat. I can't fix this problem. Can you help me for it?

[Logcat picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtkPi.png)

Kayit.java:

```
package com.ahmety.fmsocialmedia;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Kayit extends Activity {


    Button kayit;
    EditText nickname_edit,mail_edit,sifre_edit,sifre_tekrar_edit;
    String nickname,mail,sifre,sifre_tekrar,hata_mesaji="";
    boolean hata = false;
    PostClass post = new PostClass();
    String URL_POST= "http://www.ahmetyilmazz.info/kayit.php";
    JSONObject cevap=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kayit);

        kayit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        nickname_edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUsernameReg);
        mail_edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmailReg);
        sifre_edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPasswordReg);
        sifre_tekrar_edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPasswordConfirmReg);
        kayit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Edittextlerden bilgileri aldık
                nickname = nickname_edit.getText().toString();
                mail = mail_edit.getText().toString();
                sifre = sifre_edit.getText().toString();
                sifre_tekrar = sifre_tekrar_edit.getText().toString();
                int sifre_karakter = sifre.length();
                if(nickname.matches("") || mail.matches("") || sifre.matches("") || sifre_tekrar.matches("")){
                    hata = true;
                    hata_mesaji = "Please be sure fill all area!!!";
                }else if(!sifre.matches(sifre_tekrar)){
                    hata = true;
                    hata_mesaji = "Password doesn't match!!!";
                }else if(sifre_karakter<5){
                    hata_mesaji += "Password can not be smaller than 5 characater!!!";
                    hata=true;
                }else if(!Fonksiyonlar.isEmailValid(mail)){
                    hata_mesaji += "Email format is unvalid!!!";
                    hata=true;
                }
                if(hata){//hata varsa hatayı alertDialog ile gösteriyoruz
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Kayit.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage(hata_mesaji);
                    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    alertDialog.setButton(RESULT_OK,"OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            sifre_edit.setText("");
                            sifre_tekrar_edit.setText("");
                            hata_mesaji = "";
                            hata = false;
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }else{//hata yoksa
                    new KayitOl().execute();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    class KayitOl extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private String sonucmesaji,sonuc,tarih;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //  progress dialog 
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Kayit.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering is progressing...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

            sifre = Fonksiyonlar.sha1(sifre);//şifreyi sha1 ile şifreledik

            //Parametreleri ekliyoruz
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nickname", nickname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mail", mail));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sifre",sifre ));

            //Tarih bilgisini almak için 
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            tarih = format.format(c.getTime());

            String json = post.httpPost(URL_POST,"POST",params,20000);

            Log.d("Gelen Json",""+json);//Gelen veriyi logluyoruz.Log Catten kontrol edebiliriz
            try {

                cevap = new JSONObject(json);
                sonucmesaji = cevap.getString("sonucmesaji");

                if (cevap.getString("sonuc") != null) {
                    sonuc = cevap.getString("sonuc");
                    if(Integer.parseInt(sonuc) == 1){ //Eğer kayıt başarılı ise
                        //Sqlite database baglanıp gerekli verileri kaydediyoruz. 
                        Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
                        db.resetTables();
                        db.kullaniciEkle(nickname, mail, sifre, tarih); //kullanıcıyı ekliyoruz.Ve Main activitye yönlendiriyoruz.          

                        //Sonuc başarılı ise main activitye yönlendirdk.
                        Intent anasayfa = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class );
                        startActivity(anasayfa);
                        finish();

                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;        
        }       
        // Sonuç başarılı ise bu kod çalışmıcak çünkü Main activitye yönlenmiş durumda
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // closing progress dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {   
                            if(Integer.parseInt(sonuc) == 0){// Sonuç başarılı değil ise 
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Kayit.this).create();
                                alertDialog.setTitle("Hata");
                                alertDialog.setMessage(sonucmesaji);//Sonuc mesajıyla bilgilendiriyoruz.
                                alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                                alertDialog.setButton(RESULT_OK,"OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        sifre_edit.setText("");
                                        sifre_tekrar_edit.setText("");
                                    }
                                });
                                alertDialog.show();
                            }
                        }             
                });
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logcat image is showing `NumberFormatException` in your `onPostExecute()` method.

```
if(Integer.parseInt(sonuc) == 0).
```

So, I guessyour 'sonuc' string is null. Please check it once what value you get for 'sonuc'.
To avoid crash, put condition something like:

```
if(sonuc != null){
    //your code
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. sonuc is result that get register. I think its problem in php mysql. I used your code and the fault removed but it didn't register and it dont login. Thanks for your helping. I think I understand...

Comment: I am glad the it helped. :) You can give upvote or accept answer